# Optimize VBA performance of copying

Tags: excel, optimization, vba

I have to make an report by running these code with 3 parameter I,j,k.
For I runs from 1 to 5,
j run from 1 to 8,
k run from 0 to 12.
With this run, it costs me roughly 8 minutes to finish this run. 
but my I can be run up to thousands row. how can I optimize this code to run faster?

```
`Option Explicit
Sub CopySensMP()
Sheets("Sens By MP").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ts, te As Variant
ts = Time
Dim i, j, k As Integer
For k = 0 To Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Rows.Count - 1
For i = 1 To Range("Sens_MP_End")
    Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 15).Value = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 3).Value
    Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 16).Value = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 4).Value
    Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 17).Value = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 5).Value
    Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 18).Value = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 6).Value
    Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 19).Value = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 7).Value
    Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 5) = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 2) & " - MP" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(i, "000")
        For j = 1 To Range("Tbl_Sens_Plan").Count
        Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 5 + j).Value = Range("Tbl_Sens_MP").Cells(i, j).Value
        Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 14).Value = Range("Tbl_Sens_Result").Cells(i, 8 + k * 10).Value
        Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 20).Value = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 2 + k * 10).Value
        Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 21).Value = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 3 + k * 10).Value
        Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 22).Value = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 4 + k * 10).Value
        Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 23).Value = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 5 + k * 10).Value
        Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 24).Value = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 6 + k * 10).Value
        Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 27).Value = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 7 + k * 10).Value
        Cells(i + 34 + k * Range("Sens_MP_End"), 28).Value = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 1 + k * 10).Value
        Next j
    Next i
Next k
te = Time
Debug.Print te, ts
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question might be a good fit for Stack Overflow's sister site [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Does the value of your referenced range (e.g. `Sens_MP_End`) stay static?

Answer (score 2):

Bulletpoints where you could save time assuming you do not need the formulas in the referenced range s to recalculate:

- Switch to manual recalculation, then switch back to automatic at the end of the routine
- Use variables instead of references to ranges (you take a static number thousands of times)
- Reference and don't activate the sheet
- Use `Long` type instead of `Integer`
- Use `Value2` instead of `Value`

Taking the above into consideration here's a simple routine, I'm sure it can be further improved (`(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end)` saved as a variable, etc.).

```
Sub CopySensMP()
'Sheets("Sens By MP").Activate
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, sens_mp_end As Long
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sens By MP")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'manual calculation to the rescue
Dim ts, te As Variant
ts = Time
Dim i, j, k As Long 'Integer
sens_mp_end = Range("Sens_MP_End") 'why would you call a range for a static number this many times?
For k = 0 To Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Rows.Count - 1
For i = 1 To sens_mp_end
    ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 15).Value2 = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 3).Value2
    ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 16).Value2 = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 4).Value2
    ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 17).Value2 = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 5).Value2
    ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 18).Value2 = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 6).Value2
    ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 19).Value2 = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 7).Value2
    ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 5) = Range("Tbl_Sens_Scenerio").Cells(k + 1, 2) & " - MP" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(i, "000")
        For j = 1 To Range("Tbl_Sens_Plan").Count
            ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 5 + j).Value2 = Range("Tbl_Sens_MP").Cells(i, j).Value2
            ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 14).Value2 = Range("Tbl_Sens_Result").Cells(i, 8 + k * 10).Value2
            ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 20).Value2 = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 2 + k * 10).Value2
            ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 21).Value2 = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 3 + k * 10).Value2
            ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 22).Value2 = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 4 + k * 10).Value2
            ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 23).Value2 = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 5 + k * 10).Value2
            ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 24).Value2 = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 6 + k * 10).Value2
            ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 27).Value2 = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 7 + k * 10).Value2
            ws.Cells(i + 34 + k * sens_mp_end, 28).Value2 = Range("Tbl_sens_result").Cells(i, 1 + k * 10).Value2
        Next j
    Next i
Next k
te = Time
Debug.Print te, ts
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot, you have 14,21,22,23,24,27,28 in the j loop while they do not refer to j itself. You may be recalculating them way more times than you would need to.

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(i, "000")` -> `Format(i, "000")`, though you won't earn minutes by that.